# How to prevent when a user enters his own choice in a Choice column it becames a bullet

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a list with 3 columns that has the type Choice. When I add the choices for the column I check the checkbox **Allow 'Fill-in' choices** which allows the user to fill in other choices.

But when a user enters his own choice SharePoint mark the choice as a bullet. How can I fix the 3 columns with the type Choice that when a user enters his own choice it doesn't get marked as a bullet.

It has to be plain text no markup.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove border box (choice pill) only when fill-in choice is added or for all the values, even when option from choice fields options is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is showing choice pill / border because of SharePoint JSON formatting applied to your choice column.

Follow below steps to remove choice pill (border) format from fill-in choice values:

1. Go to your SharePoint list, click on settings (Gear) icon and select "List settings".
2. From list settings page, scroll down to "Columns" section and click on choice column name for which you want to make changes.
3. From column settings page, scroll down to "Column Formatting" section.
4. Copy JSON code in text box and paste it in visual studio code (or your favorite text/code editor).
5. Scroll down to the bottom of JSON code and replace below line with `""`:

   ```
   "sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-field-borderAllSolid sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary"
   ```
6. Copy the modified JSON and paste in text box under "" option on column settings page
7. Click "OK" to save changes.

**Before changing JSON**:

[image]

**After changing JSON**:

[image]